# Using regex in Global Build stats Jenkins

Tags: regex, plugins, jenkins

I am trying to use the Global Build Stats plugin to create some reports.

For example, I have the following build projects; - *Only need the all projects with the DIT in the name*

```
1st Build test, 1st build DIT, 2nd Build test, 2nd build DIT
```

I'm not really sure what to do I have used a online regex 'practice' sites and not able to make heads or tails

Comment: I had to read about the [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin) and then understand the [regex syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) being used. Please provide such informations in your question itself.

Comment: are there any particular jobs that you want to exclude? If no filters are provided, all jobs are considered by default.

Comment: Argh sorry @SilentMonk I just want to include all projects which have 'DIT' in the name

Comment: what is the current status?

Comment: Every time i click on the Global Build Stats, it sits there for a while (loading) and then completely kills chrome..

I don't get a chance to click any of the reports

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15969 this might help solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

When adding a new chart as specified [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Build+Stats+Plugin), 
in `job filtering`, select `Job name regex` and enter the regex `.*(DIT).*`.

What does this regex do?

It matches all jobs which have 'DIT' as a substring.

`.` - matches any character except for line breaks.

`*` - zero or more occurrence of the preceding character.

Comment: Hey @SilentMonk

I am still having issues with Global build stats plugin so I am now trying 'BuildMetrics' and with the same regex ' .*DIT.*  ' and it doesn't load any builds.

Comment: @craigRickett, if you don't provide any filters, are all the jobs listed? i.e in the filters column if you select `all jobs` does it show all the jobs?

Comment: @craigRickett, try with `.*` as the regex. It should show all the jobs. Then try `.*(DIT).*`.

Comment: HEYY @SlientMonk! That has worked nicely !

just wondering do you have any references that I might be able for future 'regex' issues?

Comment: @craigRickett, glad that it helped :). [This](http://regexr.com/) website is  a nice place to start. I have saved the above regex [here](http://regexr.com/3dlnc). Please upvote/accept the answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

match at pre end

```
.*(pre$).*
```

match at pre front

```
.*(^pre).*
```

match at pre end or at pre front

```
.*(^pre).*|.*(pre$).*
```